# how to make a independent, process, scheduler that will download online data

Tags: android, android-internet

I'm making android application that needs to refresh it's contents ones a day. I need some sort of a process that will even if the app is not started and this process needs to download the data that the app will use the next time is started. Any suggestions of best practices?

Comment: +1 because there is no way to say very very good question